# Set textfield to numeric only Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I trying to do textfield accept numeric only and text align to center, but it no take any effect, Isn't I set wrong properties or another way to set?

```
<TextField id="btn" android:inputType="number" android:numeric="number" android:textAlignment="center" col="1" backgroundColor="#ffffff" col="2"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First. You want to set the `keyboardType` to `number`. [See the documentation on `EditableTextBase`](http://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/ui/editable-text-base/EditableTextBase.html)

Second, about styling. You really want to set the styling within a CSS file as it helps you separate markup and style. Take a [look at the documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling) about styling.

But if you want you *can* use inline styles. However what you've done is that you've tried to pass styling as *xml parameters*. What you want to do is that you want to pass the styling to the `style` param like this:

```
<TextField style="text-align: center;"/>
```

compare that to what you did:

```
<TextField textAlignment="center"/>
```

But as said. You're gonna be a happier developer if you write your style in a separate CSS file, like:

```
<TextField cssClass="myClass">
```

and then in your CSS file:

```
.myClass {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: This changed the input to a number input, but didn't stop it from allowing symbols.

Answer (score 0):

On your submit event you could add in some validation to ensure that the input is a number. You can check this using `console.log(typeof var)` where `var` is the value of the text field, it should return integer.

You're best off setting the `text-alignment` within your CSS file.